# How to create a many to many relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So currently i have in a app:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :category
end
```

and

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :posts
end
```

which works fine as expected. However, i need to add multiple categories to a post . I thought about using has_many_and_belongs_to for each of them to acquire this but some trouble implementing this. It seems like a need to add an join table? If so, how would one look like with the setup shown above?

Any ideas?

I appreciate any input! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table should be named `categories_posts` (`categories` comes first because of alphabetical sequence) and contain `post_id` and `category_id` integer columns (indexed, most probably). The it's as simple as:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

You can create join table adding migration using:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableCategoryPost category post
```

Comment: Awesome! One last thing, how should be the table created? Simply via rails g model categories_parts or is there a different way in this specific example?

Comment: @Prometheus https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `has_many :through` to have more control over a join table.

Advantages of using `:through` for many to many relationships

- With `has_many :through` relationship you can have a model which will allow you to add validation, callbacks.
- If you initially take some extra efforts to setup many to many relationship using through it can save a lot of time and headache in future
- What if in future you want save the more information on join table like some custom sort, information about how the tables are associated which will not be allowed with `has_and_belongs_to_many`

Example

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories, through: :post_categories
  has_many :post_categories   
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, through: :post_categories
  has_many :post_categories   
end
```

Adding relationship model with rails generator command

```
rails g model post_category category_id:integer post_id:integer custom:text 

class PostCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: Thats awesome! I actually use has_many, trough: relationship already in another part in my app, but thought has_many_and_belongs_to may be the better fit in this case. Got it working with the above answer and it does the job with a few tweaks. Its actually not a category, but the user is able to choose from a few tools he has used to do 3D stuff. I think it will work fine this way. But after seeing your example, your totally right that this will give much more control. Will keep that in mind! Thanks!